# How to test browser events - click, mouseover etc. with clear native Javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, jasmine

When searching over the issues I found how to test browser events  only with Jquery. But I'm not using it.

How can I trigger some event with Javascript (NOT Jquery)?

I have a simple html form and a button with 'onclick' event.
I must simulate click event, so I can test it in Jasmine.

How can I do that?

P.S. I found some solution:

```
function fireClick(node){
    if ( document.createEvent ) {
        var evt = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
        evt.initEvent('click', true, false);
        node.dispatchEvent(evt);
    } else if( document.createEventObject ) {
        node.fireEvent('onclick') ;
    } else if (typeof node.onclick == 'function' ) {
        node.onclick();
    }
}
```

But it works only whit Jasmine standalone and not with Jasmine for node.js.

Answer (score 1):

To simulate the "click" event:

```
 var event = new Event("click");
 element.dispatchEvent(event);
```

Comment: Thanks, that only works on Jasmine standalone and not on Jasmine for node.js